# Identify whether I've received an HttpRequest or HttpResponse?

Tags: sockets, http, netty

I have a netty server that listens on a port. It can either receive HttpResponses or HttpRequests on this port. How can I set up a pipeline to handle both and distinguish between the two? Is this possible? Connections are initiated to this server and not from it.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand. An http server receives requests and sends responses. How would it ever receive an HTTP response?

Comment: It acts as a proxy server. It can also issue HTTP requests to another machine and get a HTTP response back. In this particular scenario, that other machine can also send an HTTP requests.

Comment: But you know by the state you associated with the connection what it is doing. If you accepted it, it will receive requests. If you conmected it, you will receive responses.

Comment: Not quite, in this particular setup, connections are always initiated to this server. For case number one, a TCP tunnel is initiated from some other machine to this server, after which this server sends a HTTP request to that machine. In case number two, the other machine sends a HTTP request via something like curl.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *isHttp* method from the [PortUnification](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/portunification/PortUnificationServerHandler.html) example. It examines the first two unsigned bytes of a received message to determine if it is likely an HTTP verb, therefore identifying the message as an HTTP request. You might need to modify it slightly, depending on the likely content of any responses.

```
private static boolean isHttp(int magic1, int magic2) {
  return
     magic1 == 'G' && magic2 == 'E' || // GET
     magic1 == 'P' && magic2 == 'O' || // POST
     magic1 == 'P' && magic2 == 'U' || // PUT
     magic1 == 'H' && magic2 == 'E' || // HEAD
     magic1 == 'O' && magic2 == 'P' || // OPTIONS
     magic1 == 'P' && magic2 == 'A' || // PATCH
     magic1 == 'D' && magic2 == 'E' || // DELETE
     magic1 == 'T' && magic2 == 'R' || // TRACE
     magic1 == 'C' && magic2 == 'O';   // CONNECT
}
```